# Certificate errors when accessing any server

Tags: networking, configuration, certificates

I recently installed a Ubuntu 22.04 as a Hyper-V VM, but whenever I try to compile code, go on the internet etc, I run into errors like NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID or The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: ParialChain.

I am very new to Linux, so I have no idea where to even begin, so sorry if there is already an article on this.
We have ZScaler on our physical (Windows10) machines, though it can be turned off temporarily (it re-enables itself after a few minutes). Not sure if that is important, but thought I should mention that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved it by copying my ZScaler certificate to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates

```
sudo cp <certificate> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
```

and then run

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

I hope that my little noob question and answer will help someone else :-)